# How to make GitHub ignore lines of a commit?

Tags: git, github, commit

I'm working on a project for school and I added some UI source code that doubled my line count.  I would like to keep the commit but I don't want any of it to count towards GitHub's line count.  It's not a huge issue but GitHub's line count feature was cool, but now it does not accurately reflect lines I've written.

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: Ah oh well, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Google offers lots of advice on how to Delete Git History.

Your simplest approach would be to abandon the repo, create a new repo, and copy / commit your sources into the new one. For a small repo, `git format-patch` followed by `git am` could even preserve much of the history.

For a large repo, to do it "right", you'll want [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).